# Probability of obtaining $HHT$ before $HTH$ is different from obtaining $HT$ before $TH$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Recently I came across the [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game) as I encountered the following probability question with answer.

> Given a fair coin. If we tossed the coin thrice, then the probability of obtaining $HHT$ before $HTH$ is $\frac{2}{3}.$

Just after the question above, I encounter another similar probability question with answer.

> Given a fair coin. If we tossed the coin twice and obtained either $HH$ or $TT$, we tossed twice again. If we obtained either $HT$ or $TH$, we stopped tossing. Then the probability of obtaining $HT$ and $TH$ are the same, that is, $\frac{1}{2}.$

Source: [what is the probability of BOB winning the game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622474/what-is-the-probability-of-bob-winning-the-game)

My thought:

In the first question, if we disregard the first $H$, then we are actually seeking the probability of obtaining $HT$ before $TH,$ which seems to me is the second question.

I do not understand why the answers to both questions are different.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Why would they be the same? (Also the second question, as written, seems like a totally different *kind* of question, and also wrong.. the probability is $1/4$. But even if they were analogous questions, it's unclear why the answer would be the same?)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Because both questions require obtaining $HT$ and $TH$ if we disregard the first $H$ in the three tosses? By the way, I edited my second question.

Comment: If your first two flips happen to be HH, what is the probability you will obtain HHT before HTH?

Comment: The statement you gave for the game is not right.  The game has the coin being flipped sequentially until one of the choices comes up, not three at a time.  Flipping three at a time would have equal probabilities for the two choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 coins it is of course perfectly symmetrical, so it makes sense it would be $\frac{1}{2}$ for each.

But why, you ask, would this change for $HHT$ vs $HTH$, if both sequences are the same for the first $H$, and then are followed up by the same $HT$ vs $TH$ difference?

Here's the difference: after you get that first $H$, the $HHT$ is bound to win if you get $H$ immediately after that first $H$, whereas if you get a $T$ at that point, then either $HTH$ is going to win ... or you get another $T$, and now the game 'resets'. So, the $HHT$ has an inherent advantage.

With the $HT$ vs $TH$ no such asymmetry will ever be obtained, because after the first throw the winner is immediately known.

Comment: 'With the $HT$ vs $TH$ no such asymmetry will ever be obtained, because after the first throw the winner is immediately known.' But if we obtain $HH$ or $TT,$ the game will reset and thus we do not have a winner. How do we know the winner after the first throw?

Comment: @Idonknow No, after HH the game will not reset, because if the third is a T, then HT wins. I don't think you quite understand the rules of Penney's Game ... it's not that we throw the coin some fixed number of times (equal to the lngth of the chosen sequences) and see which, if any, of the two sequences comes up. If that was the whole game, then of course every sequences would be just as likely to win, and it would be a very boring game. But the game is that you keep throwing the coin until one of the sequences comes up. So, if the sequence is HHHHT, then HT wins over TH ... and HHT over HTH

Comment: I see. You are referring to tossing the coin thrice. I thought the last statement in your answer refers to my second question.

Comment: @Idonknow I may have misunderstood the second question ... where did you find that question?

Comment: I found it in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622474/what-is-the-probability-of-bob-winning-the-game

Comment: @Idonknow OK, well, that's a completely different game than Penny's Game.  Do you realize that?

Comment: Not really. Perhaps you can explain their difference?

Comment: In Penny's game, you keep throwing the coin until one of the sequences appears. So, when you get HHHT, then HHT wins. The game does not reset after three throws.